# gvim 8.2 doesn't paste on windows 10 in powershell

Tags: powershell, vim, windows-10

I installed `vim` on Windows 10 with [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/). Copy and Paste don't work when I invoke `vim` in `powershell`. I expect them to work as long as I'm in insert mode. How can I make copy and paste work?

Comment: Moved to superuser: https://superuser.com/q/1564615/42083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://n3wjack.net/2014/08/25/setting-up-vim-on-windows/ has the answers.

Open `vim` and type the following:

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```

This will edit your `.vimrc` file wherever it might live. (On my system, it was in `c:\Users\<my_username>\.vimrc`, but you might have weird configuration issues, so just let `vim` find the file for you.

Then, copy+paste the following into the file:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim

behave mswin
```

Then save the file.

Comment: Moved to superuser: https://superuser.com/a/1564616/42083